# How to copy multiple files from multiple folders into one folder using python?

Tags: python, operating-system, rename, shutil

I have a file structure as shown in the figure. In total i have 9 folders, each folder holds 130 number of video files. I want to move the 1st video file of all 9 folders into one new folder "folder 01", and so on.
Since, the first video file of all folders will have same name, how can i solve this problem? I need some insights into solving this?

[image]

Comment: Are names of folders integers or they have different names without any logic?

Comment: you an use `shutil` to copy the files. However for the logic ... you will have to figure that out yourself. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Nikolay the names of the folders are integers (1-9). Also, the files names are integer (1.avi, 2.avi, ... 130.avi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will perform the task. I've made the assumption that the base folder for the destination path is the same as the current path.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
import os
import shutil

base_folder = os.getcwd()

# Create 130 destination folders (folder_001, ..., folder_130)
dest_folder_prefix = "folder_"
dest_path = base_folder # An assumption
dest_paths = {}
for n in range(1, 131):
    folder_number = str(n).zfill(3)
    dest_folder = os.path.join(dest_path, f'{dest_folder_prefix}{folder_number}')
    if not os.path.isdir(dest_folder):
        os.mkdir(dest_folder)
    # Store paths for quick lookup later
    dest_paths[n] = dest_folder

# Iterate through the existing folders
src_folders = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(base_folder) if os.path.isdir(f)])

for n, folder_name in enumerate(src_folders, 1):
    folder_number = str(n).zfill(2) # Used to rename destination file
    folder_path = os.path.join(base_folder, folder_name)
    # Process the list of files
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))]
    for file_name in files:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name) # e.g. '1', '.avi' for file '1.avi'
        file_number = int(name) # file name is a number
        # Set the source
        src_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
        # Set the destination filename and path
        dest_filename = f'{name}_{folder_number}{ext}' # Destination file name e.g. '1_01.avi' 
        dest_filepath = os.path.join(dest_paths[file_number], dest_filename)
        # Perform the move operation
        shutil.move(src_path, dest_filepath)
```

Comment: Thanks, works well. But what if we want to move sub-folders instead of files.

Comment: It's the same process for moving subfolders, you would need to remove the file specific portions of the code. `shutil.move()` recursively moves both files and folders. Read the documentation for more information. https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move

Comment: If we need to reverse the process, then what could be the approach. What do you think?

Comment: It would essentially be the same process. Iterate through the list of files in each of the 130 folders. The filename contains the information you need: `{name}_{folder_number}{ext}`, from this string you can determine the original folder and the original filename. Try it by repurposing the code provided in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a great function called `os.walk()` that does a lot of this for you.

You can do

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        print(file)
```

Which will print ALL of the files in the directory and subdirectories, then using this you can implement a check and use `os.rename` to rename the files accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

y can use shutil

```
import shutil

original = r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test_1\products.csv'
target = r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test_2\products.csv'

shutil.copyfile(original, target)
```

i can give you a hint ! don't hesitate to ask for clarifications

```
    def locate_path_by_substring(directory, substring, list_paths):
    for r, d, f in os.walk(directory):
        for myfile in f:
            if (substring+".log") in myfile:
                list_paths.append(os.path.join(r, myfile))
                return list_paths
```

`

```
def copy_file(original,target):
    shutil.copyfile(original, target)


def create_direct(path):
    try:
        os.mkdir(path)
    except OSError:
        print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)


def main():
    for i in range (1,131):    
        locate_path_by_substring(directory, i, list_file_{}.format(i))
        create_direct(directory+"/folder_{}".format(i))
    for i in range (1,131):
        for j in range (0,9):
            copy_file(list_file_{i}[j],directory+"/folder_{}".format(i)/)`
```