# How to copy multiple folders with numerical order including their files from multiple folders into one folder using python

Tags: python, directory, shutil

I have a file structure with 700 folders in numerical order 0001 - 0700, each folder holds the subfolder "Fixation", "Maps" with picture files. (.png) I want to either move or copy the folder "Fixation" from every folder in one new folder "Fixations" containing subfolders with the same numerical structure of the original video folder 0001-0700. All picture files are starting with 0001 and are ascending depending on the frame length of the sampled video.

---

Only the destination folder Fixations is existing all subfolders 0001 - 0700 need to be created.
How can I solve this Problem. Any solution moving or copying the folders would be greatly appreciated. Here is a visual display of the current folder structure.

Current Structure:

```
- Annotations
  - 0001
    -Fixation
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
    -Maps
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
  - 0002
    -Fixation
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
    -Maps
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
  - 0003
    -Fixation
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
    -Maps
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
```

After moving the files:

```
- Annotations
  - Fixations
    -0001
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
    -0002
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
    -0003
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
  -Maps
    -0001
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
    -0002
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
    -0003
       -0001.png , 002.png,...
```

The code i am trying to get it to work is similiar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568099/how-to-copy-multiple-files-from-multiple-folders-into-one-folder-using-python).

Any help since I am pretty new to shutil and management of files with python would be greatly appreciated.